# Seek and destroy a hanging ssh/sftp session

Tags: xubuntu, ssh, 15.10, sftp, thunar

I am using thunar to access files on a remote PC. However, sometimes the `ssh` session hangs, and I have to terminate thunar. Then when I try to log back in, thunar just hangs. The only solution I've found is to restart my local PC, and reconnect. Since this works, obviously this is something I can fix locally, by probably restarting a hanging process, instead of fully restarting the PC!

So how can I diagnose/find the hanging process/service, and restart it?

I am using Xubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Have you tried using `htop`? You can also strace and kill processes using `htop` if you use `sudo htop`

Comment: @mchid Yes, but I have no idea what to look for. There isn't anything with the string `sftp`, and I find only one process with the string `ssh`: `/usr/sbin/sshd -D`, but it is owned by root, so I don't think its relevant (I never used `sudo` to connect to the remote PC in the first place).

Comment: You can also use f3 to search if it helps but it looks like you probably know that.

Comment: @mchid Yeah that's what I use, and that's what I find.

Answer (score 1):

question is quite old, but I still using 16.04.
Maybe someone else still searching this.

To seek process:

```
sudo ps -ax | grep sftp

11806 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-sftp --spawner :1.17 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/8
11817 pts/6    Ss+    0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -oForwardX11 no -oForwardAgent no -oPermitLocalCommand no -oClearAllForwardings yes -oProtocol 2 -oNoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes -l myusername -s mysite.org sftp
11821 pts/7    Ss+    0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -oForwardX11 no -oForwardAgent no -oPermitLocalCommand no -oClearAllForwardings yes -oProtocol 2 -oNoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes -l myusername -s mysite.org sftp
11825 pts/10   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto sftp
```

To destroy:

```
# 11817 - is the pid of ssh process
kill -9 11817
```